# How to modify vdso variable (vvar)?

Tags: c, linux, vdso

Recently I am study vdso in linux. I tried to modify the data in `vvar` section but it failed. Following is what I've tried.

According to [lwn](https://lwn.net/Articles/615809/) described, there're two address for `vvar`:

> The first one is a regular kernel-space address whose value is greater than PAGE_OFFSET. If you look at the System.map file, you'll find that this symbol has an address like ffffffff81c76080.

> The second address is in a region called the "vvar page". The base address (VVAR_ADDRESS) of this page is defined in the kernel to be at 0xffffffffff5ff000, close to the end of the 64-bit address space. This page is made available read-only to user-space code.

Modify by first address: First address is easy to find by checking the address of `_vdso_data` in `/boot/System.map-kernel-version`. After getting the address, I modify the member (`__unused`) of it in kernel module ( thus, there's not permission issue ). Then, I check the `__unused` from user space program, it still remain `0` which means that I failed to modify it from kernel space.

Modify by second address: Second address can be found by auxiliary vector. After getting the address of `vdso`, then we can find `vvar` section. I pass this address into kernel module and modify its member `__unused`. The the error occur, showing the permission error issue. ( The reason should be `vvar` is read-only memory, checking by `cat /proc/pid/maps` )

I think the first way is almost at the solution but it seems `vvar` at that address is not be mapped to all process' `vvar` section. Are there any idea? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]: The first way get more closer to solution. I modify the cr0 bit, thus allow permission of writing. Even I successfully write it, it still can't be read from linux kernel (by getting vdso_data through `__arch_get_k_vdso_data` and accessing its member which I modify in user space + kernel module previously)

Comment: Not sure I understood what you tried and what has been the issue. The VDSO areay is already defined. What you need is to add / modify a member in the structure and provide a function that will fills the corresponding member periodicalluy (or once, depending on the case).

Comment: In linux kernel, we can modify it by accessing vdso_data structure(`__arch_get_k_vdso_data`). Now, what I tried to modify from user space + kernel module.